# How to produce a polynomial trend line equation that takes three arrays as parameters?

Tags: regression, trend, polynomial

Does anyone know of any programming code for producing a polynomial trend line equation that takes three arrays as parameters, ie X, Y and Weight?

Or even if you could explain in English how such a program would work.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean polynomial regression, then a good resource is the found at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression), in the programming language of your choice. I personally enjoy using the [C/GSL](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#C) example.

Generally speaking, the gist of polynomial regression is the same as linear regression (or weighted regression) in that you have to solve for the least squares/maximum likelihood estimates of the coefficients $\hat{\beta}=(X^TWX)^{-1}X^TWY$, except that columns of your matrix $X$ now include polynomial transformations of the original data.

A more complex alternative would be [locally weighted regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression#Definition_of_a_LOESS_model), which involves fitting the above model, weighted polynomial regression, to each observation. However, the weights $W$ used at each observation are a function of how far the other observations are from the current one. An example of such a function would be the [Gaussian kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_kernel).